# passing a base64 image through stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routes, base64

I am trying to send a base-64 encoded image through a stateParam.  It seems that when it reaches the other route, and I try to populate an image tag it does not work (A small image not found icon is shown).

However, it works perfectly if I just take the string and populate a test image tag without sending it through the route.

This works (The onSuccess part):

```
angular.module('app.cameraCtrl', [])

.controller('cameraCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

    $scope.momentPicture = document.getElementById('momentPicture');

    $scope.camera = function() {
        console.log("CAMERA");
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
            { quality: 50, //Quality of photo 0-100
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, //File format, recommended FILE_URL
            allowEdit: false,   //Allows editing of picture
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            correctOrientation: true
        });

        function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            var picture = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
            $scope.momentPicture = document.getElementById('momentPicture');
            $scope.momentPicture.src = picture;
            $state.go('textOverlay', {'picture': picture });
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
    };
}])
```

This does not:

```
angular.module('app.textOverlayCtrl', [])

.controller('textOverlayCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

    (function init() {
        $scope.momentPicture = document.getElementById('momentPicture');
        $scope.momentPicture.src = $stateParams.picture;
    })();

}])
```

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

camera.html (Works)

```
<ion-view title="Camera" id="page4">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <button id="camera-button8" ng-click="camera()" class="button button-positive  button-block">Camera</button>
    <button id="camera-button9" class="button button-assertive  button-block">Upload</button>
    <img id="momentPicture" ng-src = "test"></img>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

textOverlay.html (Does not work)

```
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div style="margin: 0px; line-height: 250px; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 239); text-align: center;">
      <i class="icon ion-image" style="font-size: 64px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); vertical-align: middle;"></i>
    </div>
    <img id="momentPicture" ng-src="momentPicture"></img>
    <form id="camera-form4" class="list">
      <label class="item item-input" id="camera-input1">
        <span class="input-label">Input</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
      </label>
    </form>
    <button id="camera-button7" class="button button-positive  button-block">Text Overlay</button>
    <div id="camera-button-bar1" class="button-bar">
      <button id="camera-button4" ng-click="camera()" class="button button-positive  button-block">Submit</button>
      <button id="camera-button6" ng-click="back()" class="button button-positive  button-block button-outline">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: does your `$stateProvider` configuration implicitly says there is a `$stateParams`?

Comment: Yes, the param is being correctly passed.  I was able to console.log from textOverlay and it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so there's two different ways of setting the source of an `img` with an angular variable, and it looks like you're trying to do both of them and they're sort of cancelling each other out.

The first way is to just use `ng-src` as so in your Text Overlay Controller in the `init()` function just do:

```
$scope.momentPicture = $stateParams.picture;
```

And in your template use:

```
<img id="momentPicture" ng-src="{{momentPicture}}"/>
```

Remember `momentPicture` is a `$scope` variable so it needs to be interpolated using `{{ }}`. Also there's no need to set the base64 string to `$scope.momentPicture.src` that'll just make things more confusing, just set it to `$scope.momentPicure`.

The other way you can do this is as follows:

Your Text Overlay Controller should look like this:

```
angular.module('app.textOverlayCtrl', [])

.controller('textOverlayCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

    (function init() {
        var momentPicture = document.getElementById('momentPicture'); //Doesn't really need to be a $scope variable
        momentPicture.setAttribute('src', $stateParams.picture);
    })();

}])
```

And then in your template drop the `ng-src`:

```
<img id="momentPicture"/>
```

If the second way doesn't work it might be because you are trying to access a DOM element before it has loaded with `document.getElementById`.

Let me know if this works! :)

Comment: The variable is being correctly passed to the next state, I am able to console.log it.  My stateprovider uses the params option to specify the state.

Comment: Ok, so @MatTaNg you can print out the entire base64 encoded image when it comes back through yes? In that case it may be an issue with how you are attempting to display the image. Could you update your question to include your html file to see how that's being done please.